# Añadir una animación con retardo al re-imprimir una plantilla en Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cuál un usuario puede dar votos positivos o negativos a cada elemento, en este saco, sitios web, y que filtra los resultados de mayor a menor número de votos.

El problema viene cuando un elemento adquiere mas votos que otro, la plantilla es reactiva por lo cuál cambia inmediatamente de posición el elemento, y lo que necesito es que haya una animación retardada para que sea mas cómodo visualmente para el usuario.

El código de la plantilla es este principal es este:

```
Template.sites_listing.helpers({
    websites: function () {

        if (Session.get("userFilter")) {// they set a filter!
            // return Websites.find({createdBy: Session.get("userFilter")}, {sort: {createdOn: -1, rating: -1}});
        }
        else {
            return Websites.find({}, {sort: {'votes.Up': -1}});
        }

    }
});
```

Y este es el código del evento de la plantilla de cada objeto:

```
Template.website_item.events({
    "click .js-upvote": function (event) {
        var website_id = this._id;
        console.log("Up voting website with id " + website_id);

        Websites.update({_id: website_id},
            {$inc: {'votes.Up': 1}});


        return false;
    },
    "click .js-downvote": function (event) {
        var website_id = this._id;
        console.log("Down voting website with id " + website_id);

        Websites.update({_id: website_id},
            {$inc: {'votes.Down': 1}});

        return false;
    }
});
```

He encontrado un ejemplo del código pero no sé como condicionarlo para que al momento de actualizar la plantilla y mover un elemento por encima del otro pueda agregar una animación:

```
// use jquery to hide the image component
   // then remove it at the end of the animation
   $("#"+image_id).hide('slow', function(){
    Images.remove({"_id":image_id});
   })
```

Alguién tiene idea de como hacer esto?

Comment: No tengo un respuesta corta para eso, pero exactamente lo que quieres hacer está en estas dos páginas. http://www.webtempest.com/meteorjs-animation http://es.discovermeteor.com/chapters/animations/

Answer (score 1):

Hola te recomiendo que eso eventos de rende rizado los hagas directamente en

```
Template.website_item.events({
    "click .js-upvote": function (event) {
        var website_id = this._id;
        Session.set('idImage', website_id); 
        console.log("Up voting website with id " + website_id);

        Websites.update({_id: website_id},
            {$inc: {'votes.Up': 1}});


        return false;
    },
    "click .js-downvote": function (event) {
        var website_id = this._id;
        Session.set('idImage', website_id); 
        console.log("Down voting website with id " + website_id);

        Websites.update({_id: website_id},
            {$inc: {'votes.Down': 1}});

        return false;
    }
});

Template.sites_listing_new.rendered = function() {
   var image_id = Session.get('idImage'); 
   $("#"+image_id).hide('slow', function(){
    Images.remove({"_id":image_id});
   }) 
}
```